# CodeIgniter Not Able to load REST Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I am trying to set up Philip Sturgeon’s REST Library. I did exactly what the Readme file told me to do:

Drag and drop the **application/libraries/Format.php** and **application/libraries/REST_Controller.php** files into your application’s directories. Either autoload the `REST_Controller` class or `require_once` it at the top of your controllers to load it into the scope. Additionally, copy the **rest.php** file from **application/config** in your application’s configuration directory.

I dragged three files into corresponding folders. I also checked out this article on Nettus: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

I try to autoload it using:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('REST_Controller', 'database', 'session', 'form_validation');
```

I also tried

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'REST_Controller', '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

And then at last I tried:

```
require(APPPATH'.libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

They all don’t work. Also I’m very certain I am using CodeIgniter **2.1.4**, because I downloaded fresh from the main website.

Does anyone know what’s going on?

**By they don't work, I mean the server crashed (I use MAMP).**

Comment: Please direct me to CodeIgniter 2.2 because I appear to be stuck on 2.1.4 as of 9/16/2013

Comment: You'll need to describe what "they don't work" means or we can't help you

Comment: @MonkeyZeus My apology, I also use 2.1.4. It was a mistake saying 2.2

Comment: @jmadsen Don't work means my server crashed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this may be it will work for you because its working fine for me.

require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

Comment: I might not try this. I kinda give up on REST library and I start to write one for myself. It's not that hard :)

Comment: Can't we autoload Rest Controller?